# Python: How to read data from webpage and then write back from database?

Tags: python, database, html, interactive

I am a beginner. 
I want to read two inputs (probably from a slide down menu) from a web page and use them as variables to execute python program, then return the result to a database and also display it on the webpage. I`m using mySQL for database management.

Comment: This question is a little too broad - you really should try something and show what you've tried.  To get you started you're probably going to want to use some sort of framework to interface python with the web (for example Django).  You'll then give your drop down lists a name and use something like request.POST.get('name') to retrieve the data from the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scrape through any other website and get details from their site.
There are two cases

---

1. Data does not change on the webpage once web page gets loaded in this case what you see in the view page source in the browser is as what you see in the web page then you can send a get request to get the data from the web page url using [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). once you get the data from the web site you can parse the data using [beautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). This works well for static web pages once you parse the web page you can get the data from it and you can add it to the data base using Mysql insert statement
2. If the data is dynamic that is page content changes after web page is loaded then  you can use either [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) or [Python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) there are many other tools available with those you can get the data that is needed and inset it into database

Answer (score 0):

so, for take the value from the element you have to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("yourwebpage")
item=browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath of your element")
value=item.text
```

instead than text you can use also:tag_name, size, location, id attribute etc

after for the DB:

```
import pypyodbc
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                    'Server=yorserver;'
                                    'Database=yourdb;'
                                    'uid=youruser;pwd=yourpassword')
cursor = connection.cursor() 
cursor.execute("your_query_to_update_the_db_fields")
self.connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Sorry if it's not very clear but you didn't give me a lot of details so I just sent a general code